# angular 6 url parameter

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

im passing slug by `router.navigate` to use slug in another component

```
GetTagPost(slug) {
  return this.router.navigate(["blog/view-hot-tags/", slug])
}
```

i should have url like:
`http://localhost:4200/blog/view-hot-tags/bb`

but angular will turn it like:

`http://localhost:4200/blog/view-hot-tags;0=bb`

why???

other route for example documents/single-view/:id' work correctly and parameter will seprate by "/" not ";" any idea ???

router.ts:

```
  {path: 'documents',component: DocsComponent},
  {path: 'documents/single-view/:id', component: ViewSingleDocComponent},
  {path: 'documents/single-cat-view/:id', component: ViewSingleCatDocComponent},
  {path: 'blog/:id', component: ViewSingleBlogComponent},
  {path: 'blog/view-hot-tags/:id', component: ViewBlogByTagComponent},
  {path: 'loginM', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginNmComponent},
  {path: '', component: ProductComponent, pathMatch: 'full', 
     data: {breadcrumb: "home"},
  },
```

component.html:

```
    <div class="tag_name">
      <a (click)="GetTagPost(tag?.tag)">#{{tag?.tag}}</a>
    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
  GetTagPost(slug) {
    return this.router.navigate(["blog/view-hot-tags/", slug])
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what your slug looks like ?

Comment: yes its a simple string it "bb" for test

Comment: How about a working sample? https://stackblitz.com

Comment: My bet is that it's not 'bb', but an array containing a single element 'bb'.

Comment: oh you right @JBNizet its a array angular try to use it as string thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GetTagPost(slug) {
return this.router.navigate(["blog/view-hot-tags", { id : slug }]); }
```

It would provide http://localhost:4200/blog/view-hot-tags?id=bb and it would work fine. It is querystring format.

OR

```
GetTagPost(slug) {
return this.router.navigate(["blog/view-hot-tags/"+slug ]); }
```

I would provide http://localhost:4200/blog/view-hot-tags/bb

Comment: Why are you getting that semicolon, and what do you want it to be??

Comment: I updated the answer, if none of these are working, then you are not sharing the error causing code.

Comment: hi thanks for help i found the problem was the slug ,value  it seems its a array i cast it as string